# Broken pipe when grepping output, but only with -i flag

Tags: grep, pipe, pip, case-sensitivity

I'm trying to see if a certain python-library is installed by grepping the output of `pip list`. If I try this

`pip list | grep -q $package`, it works fine. If I try `pip list | grep -qi $package`, I get the following error output

```
pi@pibox:~ $ pip list | grep -i -q pyyaml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 248, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 156, in main
    logger.fatal('Exception:\n%s' % format_exc())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/log.py", line 111, in fatal
    self.log(self.FATAL, msg, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/log.py", line 164, in log
    consumer.flush()
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

this seems to be an error on the python side of things, what would the grepm flag to ignore case have to do with pip's ability to send information down a pipe?

This is on a Raspberry Pi 3 running `pip 1.5.6 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)` and `grep (GNU grep) 2.20`.

Comment: similar stuff [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3263)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With the `-q` flag the `grep` program will stop immediately when the first line of data matches.

However `pip` may still be trying to send data into the pipe.  It will receive a SIGPIPE.  And that causes the error traceback.

With the `-i` flag it's possible that the `grep` process is stopping sooner (earlier match), before `pip` has finished writing out the results.

Normally you shouldn't use `-q` in a pipeline like this unless you are sure the program at the other end can handle SIGPIPE.

So `pip list | grep -i $packagename` will work without error.

Comment: I was trying to use `-q` because it just gives the exit code that I need for the script, doing it without that flag results in it working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The exit code will be the same; you can do `grep -i $packagename >/dev/null` to throw the output away.

Comment: Thankyou so much. Man, that was a painful hour trying to figure WTF was going on!